# Making a star pyramid in C#

Tags: c#

So I'm trying to do a pyramid in C# but I can't get it to print properly.
I'm doing this for my school's C# class, can't really figure out how to get the spaces in the pyramid properly. I feel like I'm really doing something wrong here.

Instead of a triangle I'm getting something like this:

```
   *
   **
  ***
  ****
 *****
 ******
*******
********
```

Here is my code:

```
using System;

namespace Pyramidi
{
    class Ohjelma
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int korkeusMax = 0;
            int valit = 0;
            do
            {
                Console.Write("Anna korkeus: ");            
                korkeusMax = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());           
                if (korkeusMax > 0) {
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    continue;
                }          
            }
            while(true);

            for (int korkeus = 1; korkeus <= korkeusMax; korkeus++)
            {

                valit = (korkeusMax - korkeus) / 2;
                for (int i = 0; i < valit; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
                for (int leveys = 1; leveys <= korkeus; leveys++)
                {
                    Console.Write("*");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

                Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah sorry I typed too quickly, you will struggle to get it how your thinking, the only thing you can really do is add spaces between the stars on the even number lines (or have them left-aligned)

Comment: I know, but I'm not exactly sure what is causing the stars to appear like that.

Edit: If I wanted to go on about having a pyramid, how would I go for it? Left-aligned is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (int korkeus = 0; korkeus < korkeusMax; korkeus++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (korkeusMax - korkeus - 1); i++)
    {
        Console.Write(" ");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < (korkeus * 2 + 1); i++)
    {
        Console.Write("*");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Alternatively, instead of loops, you can use `new String('*', num)`. Try this:

```
for (int korkeus = 0; korkeus < korkeusMax; korkeus++)
{

    Console.Write(new String(' ', korkeusMax - korkeus - 1));
    Console.Write(new String('*', korkeus * 2 + 1));
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: This seems to work. Sadly this school assignment must be done using for() loops, so we actually learn to use them. :(

Comment: "Sadly this school assignment must be done using for() loops, so we actually learn to use them." <- this is where education fails... that's why I left university... they do not accept alternatives, they want to force people to one scheme... ridiculous.

Comment: I know right. Anyways I got it working with for loops, did the same with while loops.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the first half right, but what you want to do for the second half is another for loop that does the opposite.

So you probably want to copy your for loop and change the header from

```
 for (int korkeus = 1; korkeus <= korkeusMax; korkeus++)
```

to

```
 for (int korkeus = kokeusMax; korkeus > 1; korkeus--)
```

or something along those lines